# Malformed field names in Symfony JsonResponse

Tags: php, symfony

I have a strange problem with Symfony's `JsonResponse` that I cannot seem to figure out. I have the following action in my controller:

```
public function loadTemplateAction($id)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Host');
    $template = $repository->find($id);

    return new JsonResponse((array)$template);
}
```

It's supposed to find the given template in my repository by the passed id. I want to use the returned data in an ajax call. It does what I want, but it seems to "prefix" all the field names with an asterisk. So it returns a response like this:

[image: Console output]

I can't figure out why it's putting those asterisks in front of the field names (they are obviously not named that way in my datasource). Does anybody have a clue what could be causing this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are
>   unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; **protected variables have a '*' prepended** to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.
>   This can result in some unexpected behaviour:

You probably should not just typecast your object to arrays and JSON encode them. Have a look at some of the serialization solutions that exist:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

These libraries offer great control on how to serialize your objects to different formats, including JSON.

If you need less control on how your objects are serialized to JSON, you could just implement the [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface.

Comment: Thanks, using the JsonEncoder with the Serializer component did the trick! The fields were indeed protected properties of my entity, so that explains as much.

Comment: Careful not to create a JsonResponse with already serialized output, that will result in a double encoding.